# What would cause my shower soap dish to fall off, and how should I go about fixing it?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, tile, bathroom-fixtures

Apparently the weight of a shampoo bottle was too much for this soap dish holder. My house was built sometime in the early 80's and I suspect this was original to the house.

Could this just be age and a weak attachment, or does this seem like a larger issue I need to investigate further somehow?

What should I be looking for to determine why this happened and what should I do to fix this?

[image: broken wall in shower]

Comment: The shampoo bottle was just the straw that broke the camel's back. The soap dish was likely used over the years as a grab bar, and it was not designed or mounted for that purpose so eventually the tile pulled off the wall. The soap dish actually stayed attached to the tile.

Comment: Yes you are totally right. After I wrote this I want back and looked at it closer. Yeah the drywall was obviously holding all the weight here. Is this repairable as it is, or do I need to look into something more involved? That wall seems to have a bit of flex to it if i lightly push on the tiles above where it fell off.

Comment: What's behind the drywall? It's not beyond the realms of possibility you could attach it through to that, or to something more substantial added securely to that. That would make the rest of the job just a patch-up.

Comment: It looks like there some clear plastic and then some insulation.  Beyond that i'm not sure, but it would be an exterior wall.

Comment: I'd be inclined to weigh up your chances of enlarging the hole, solidly screwing one or more wood blocks to the real wall, then re-fixing the holder to those. The patch-up job is approximately the same deal, even if the hole is a bit bigger. Get the wood right depth & you've got something to fasten a bit of drywall to too.

Comment: What would cause my shower soap dish to fall off? *shaped like a grab bar*. How should I go about fixing it? By *not putting it back*. Any tile left over in the basement? Or you at least still have the third one? Clean up the back sides so they dry fit good (and the grout off the sides, and some that's still on the inside on the wall if possible), then put 'em back in with way too much mastic and forget about patching wall. Prop up the dish somehow with a board unless you want to hold it there for 24h. Mastic is sticky but it ain't *that* sticky.

Comment: I second that!  This wasn't grabbed to make it fall off but I'm sure it has been in the past. When I get around to fixing this I plan to not install a replacement, just blank tiles.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not even sure that grout had to fail for that dish to pull off.  It was just ultimately just being held by the paper on the sheetrock (dish grouted to tiles; tiles attached to sheetrock), nothing structural.

If it were me, I would build a niche there like this:

1. Remove a couple of more tiles around the torn opening.
2. Frame the opening (sides, top & bottom) in with 2x4's or 3/4" water resistant plywood.
3. Cover the inside of the opening with 1/4" cement board.
4. Tape & seal all joints.
5. Seal with something like Red Guard on the inside.
6. Tile & grout the inside.

Something like this:

[image]

Here's what it looks like completed, 7 years ago.

[image]

**Another Option**

You can cut the tiles in the corner so as to provide a lip or recess into which a piece of tile or a soap holder can be fitted, like this (from Icreatables):

[image]

The recesses hold the tile from falling down (sort of like corner shelf brackets).  The grout just serves to keep the shelf from pulling out and preventing water ingress.

Comment: Why not buy a plastic niche?  So much less work and less to go wrong.

Comment: Sure, that'll work.  I've added a picture of what mine looked like when finished.

Comment: Those look like great ways to add a place to put your soap but even if you do a nice job and waterproof the niche the rest of your tile is still set on an unsuitable substrate.  I would not put in the effort.  That tile in the corner solution will catch water that will seep into the wall instead of dripping down eventually damaging that spot and it would be difficult to impossible to cleanly remove more tiles for a niche install without destroying more drywall (although you're already patching that).

Answer (score 2):

The grout failed, allowing water to get to the drywall, compromising the holding strength.  Then something or someone impacted the dish enough to cause it to overcome the remaining resistance that was allowing it to hang to the wall.

Repair is tricky. There appears to be old inferior moisture resistant drywall that the tiles are set on. Often when this type of thing happens it is an indication of a larger scale issue with grout failure and other places of water infiltration.

A skilled handyman or possible tile craftsman could fabricate a method to get new backing just in the area of missing tile and seal it enough to get new tiles set.  However it may be impossible to find that size and color tile.
Any repair may be a noticeable scar and unsatisfactory. You best bet is to think about having a pro look at the walls and give an opinion if a repair is even an option, or if you would be throwing good money at a bad wall.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this. I am not skilled in these areas at all and I wanted to get some general feedback before I looked into anything further. Everything you are saying makes perfect sense. I will most certainly call someone soon and get their assessment on it.

Comment: I'm not even sure that grout had to fail for that dish to pull off.  It was just being ultimately just being held by the paper on the sheetrock (dish grouted to tiles; tiles attached to sheetrock), nothing structural.

Comment: @SteveSh, those are usually pushed into the thin set used for the tiles. the idea is the thin set goes into holes in the back of the soap dish and holds it.  But yeah you are right , its something that the builders figure will last until the warranty is up and in a few years it's all falling appart.

Comment: I could repair that to its exact original state no problem, except that's the problem, +1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that tile is set on drywall.  There is no waterproof layer.  At the end of the day, this is not a suitable substrate for tile.  The drywall might be mildew resistant but the gypsum will soften and fall apart.  Grout isn't waterproof unless it is some special epoxy stuff and if they used drywall they didn't spring for epoxy grout.  Not all types of tile are waterproof either.  The drywall is also not particularly stable.  There are showers with tiles set on drywall out there that have lasted decades and may last another few due to specific conditions and use patterns but yours is clearly not one of those.

The underlying problem is that the tile is set on drywall.  You could probably manage to put just the dish soap back by adding blocking and patching the drywall but that won't address the issue.  The "proper" fix is tare out the walls, rebuild them with proper tile underlayment material like cement board or special foam board, all with proper waterproofing, and set the tile with mortar instead of glue like what it looks like you have there.

Comment: Good to know, thank you. This is thankfully in a rarely used guest bathroom, but I have no idea the usage pattern before I moved in earlier this year. I will most likely opt for the quick/cheap fix for the time being and when I have a bit more cash flow I can "properly" fix this somehow.  If I can just get the wall patched and put a lighter soap dish there as a replacement I think it might last. The one that fell off was quite heavy solid ceramic, which obviously wasn't attached well either

Comment: As previously noted, the dish was attached very well, since it took the wall tiles with it.

Comment: If that's the way you have to go, I would replace the tiles and keep the soap on the corner of the tub.  With any luck, you might be able to free the original tiles from the back of the holder if that's attached with silicone.

Comment: Drywall is not a suitable substrate for *tub surround* tile.  It would have been fine for a backsplash or other not-wet location.

Comment: @Huesmann Right, if you just glue it up where there's negligible water it will be fine.  That's not the situation here.